# CSS rounded corners ignored by a:hover background? (Twitter-Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a little bit confused with the Twitter-Bootstrap navbar and it's rouned corners. I've defined rouned corners for the navbar. And when you hover over the navbar with the cursor, the a:hover background seems to ignore the corners.

Here are some screenshots:

> Looks nice with smooth corners.
>
> [image: Normal, with rounded corners.]
>
> And this happens on a:hover
>
> [image: And this happens on a:hover]

How can I define a:hover in CSS not to override the corners? I know one way is to use image files, but this option is not suitable at the moment.

---

## EDIT:

I've managed to make the left-side a:hover curved using @Radian's code, however, the right-side menu a:hover effects get completely messed up.

This code should add the rouned corners for the first menu link, what it actually does, but with a few unwanted effects.

```
  .navbar .nav > li:first-child a {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px !important;
}
```

And the effects are below:

> 1) This looks okay, just as I need it to be.
>   [image]
>
> 2) That however, isn't okay.
>   [image]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maku1337/GD23q and http://jsfiddle.net/maku1337/GD23q/embedded/result/ for more clear view.

Comment: Can you apply `border-radius: 15px;` in the CSS to the `a:hover`?

Comment: Reduced case in JSFiddle please. My guess is that it's the link that when hovered does not have a border-radius.

Comment: Most likely the rounded corners are applied to the navigation element itself, not the links – and then the background of the link breaks that look, because the link itself is still rectangular. Giving the (first) link a border-radius on the left corners should fix that.

Comment: @CBroe True, I applied the rounded corners to the whole .navbar class. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: I think you can leave the rounded corners for the `.navbar` – but give the same `border-radius` to the first link’s left corners, so that it takes the same “shape”.

Comment: @CBroe Hmm... It doesn't seem to work for me though. The class which I'm trying to use is: 

  `.navbar .nav > li > a:nth-child(first)`

Comment: Without any HTML code just showing one CSS selector won’t help.

Comment: @CBroe Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maku1337/GD23q/ (http://jsfiddle.net/maku1337/GD23q/embedded/result/ for more clear view)

Answer (score 3):

i write this code maybe that can help you,
that's work in modern browser:

jsfiddle.net/C6zV8/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I modified your code a bit, to fit my needs though :)

Answer (score 2):

Posting the final solution for the problem which worked for me:

```
.navbar .nav > li:first-child a {
 border-top-left-radius: 6px !important;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px !important;}
```